# html: iframe is not showing pdf document using Angular

Tags: html, iframe, angular9

in Angular 9 module iframe has a floating error: not showing pdf document

```
<iframe [src]="dialogData?.documentSource">
</iframe>
```

dialogData?.documentSource is coming, pdf is downloading in another tab
there are no errors in console
what can be the reason of not showing in iframe?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, without the use of extra JavaScript libraries such as PDFObject, Angular wont show PDFs in an iFrame. Or you could try [this](https://angularquestions.com/2020/09/09/angular-show-pdf-file-in-html-iframe-instead-of-downloading/) out